Effect of an element of group algebra in the kernel of module endomorphisms
Let $G$ be a finite group, $K$ be field, and $M$ be a $KG$ module. The $KG$-module structure of $\text{End}_K(M)$ is given by $$g\cdot \tau(x)=g\tau(g^{-1}x);\ \forall x \in M,$$
for every $\tau \in \text{End}_K(M)$ and $g \in G$. Consider the map $N_G: \text{End}_K(M) \to \text{End}_{KG}(M) $ via $$N_G:\tau \mapsto \sum_g g \cdot \tau.$$
I want to know when $\ker(\tau)=\ker(N_G \tau)$ for the cases when $|G| \in K^{\times}$ and $|G| \not \in K^{\times}$.
If this question is too general, what condition $\tau$ should have such that $\ker(\tau)=\ker(N_G \tau)$ provided that that $\ker(\tau)$ is a $KG$-submodule of $M$?
For example, if $ \tau \in \text{End}_{KG}(M)$, then $N_G \tau=|G|\tau$, so this condition, together with $ |G| \in K^{\times}$, gives the desired condition.

It is more natural to consider this question for two $KG$-modules $M,N$ and $\tau : M \to N$. Then we may assume that $M = KG$ (why?), but $N$ remains arbitrary. Now you can rewrite your condition in terms of elements of $N$.
